# На что указывает файловый дескриптор и связь с inode?

Tags: c++, linux, c

Правильно я понимаю, что файловый дескриптор это индекс в таблице в который есть ссылка на структуру FILE, в которой есть inode, а также сам fd хранится, и другая информация, типа смещение в файле, текущая позиция.

А inode это индекс с указанием мета информации, например где хранится файл на жеском диске.

Comment: Точнее системный вызов stat возвращает структуру, и fd указывает на эту структуру?

Comment: файловый дескриптор это просто число (да, там может быть все что угодно, например, указатель), по которому ОС может идентифицировать конкретный файл (или что то файлоподобное). Все остальное - это детали реализации.

Comment: Да, я понимаю что это число в таблице, но там есть и структурка на которую указывает эта запись, по примеры linux  на какую структуру будет указывать? На ту которую возвращает stat?

Comment: да, но это внутренние дела ядра. оно может меняться от версии к версии. Какую задачу Вы хотите решить? если что - в линукс дескрипторы вообще выдаются числами, начиная с нуля и до победного конца. То есть, просто числа. А уже ядро имеет таблицу, где по этим числам можно получить данные.

Comment: Для общей картины мира, открываешь статью, написано что файловый дескриптор число возвращаемое ОС, ок думаешь, число в таблице и что дальше? Дальше понимаешь, что указывает на какую то запись, на какую?  Inode структура данных в которой хранится информация о файле, где он прикрепляется к файлу, связан он с той структурой на которую указывает fd, вот так и возникают вопросы, в инете чётко найти ответа не нашлось, и вот спросил правильно ли примерно все понимаю или нет

Comment: тогда откройте любую книгу по устройству линукса и почитайте. Но файловый дескрпитор в линуксе может указывать на сокет, а там inode не будет

Comment: Можете посоветовать?

Comment: я бы почитал вот это https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/ (оно бесплатно). Там описывается, как писать драйвера для линукса, Драйвер диска это как раз то, что Вы хотите, просто с другой стороны. В любом случае, Вы хотите узнать внутренности ядра. Для других ОС нужно искать свои книги.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Правильно я понимаю, что файловый дескриптор это индекс в таблице в который есть ссылка на структуру

Да, по сути *номер файлового дескриптора* (тот что возвращается системным вызовом `open()`, и используется в `read()` и т.п.) — это индекс в массиве указателей на структуры, которые представляют открытые файлы текущего процесса.

Доступ на стороне ядра к нему выглядит, условно, следующим образом: `current->files->fdt->fd[i]`, где:

- `current` — [`struct task_struct`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.5/source/include/linux/sched.h#L723) — текущий процесс
- [`files`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.5/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1068) — [`struct files_struct`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.5/source/include/linux/fdtable.h#L49) — таблица открытых файлов задачи
- [`fdt`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.5/source/include/linux/fdtable.h#L57) — [`struct fdtable`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.5/source/include/linux/fdtable.h#L27) — небольшая структура, инкапсулирующая массив
- [`fd`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.5/source/include/linux/fdtable.h#L29) — массив указателей на [`struct file`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.5/source/include/linux/fs.h#L962)

При этом разные задачи могут ссылаться на одну таблицу открытых файлов (так, например реализуются потоки), а некоторые записи в этой таблице могут ссылаться на один и тот же файл (так реализуется, например [`dup(2)`](https://ru.manpages.org/dup2/2)).

> в которой есть inode, а также сам fd хранится, и другая информация, типа смещение в файле, текущая позиция.

Да, `struct file` по сути и является файловым дескриптором. В нём есть [текущее смещение](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.5/source/include/linux/fs.h#L981), [путь](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.5/source/include/linux/fs.h#L967) по которому был открыт файл, и [операции над этим файлом](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.5/source/include/linux/fs.h#L969), а также и [указатель](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.5/source/include/linux/fs.h#L968) на данные кешированные из инода, и некоторые другие данные, необходимые для работы с файлом.

> А inode это индекс с указанием мета информации, например где хранится файл на жеском диске.

Здесь немого сложнее: есть инода ([`struct inode`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.5/source/include/linux/fs.h#L620)), как абстракция ОС. По сути она содержит те же метаданные, которые возвращает [`stat(2)`](https://ru.manpages.org/stat/2), как тип файла, владелец права доступа, временные метки и т.п., а также *номер иноды*.

А есть инода, как структура в конкретной файловой системе. И она уже [обычно] содержит (по мимо тех же метаданных, что описывались выше), информацию о том, как расположены данные самого файла на диске. Эти данные ФС-специфичны и при чтении с диска хранятся драйвером ФС отдельно.